# Div not positioned below absolute div

Tags: css, xhtml, css-position

I have the following code at http://jsfiddle.net/qPtXL/

As you can see the problem is the `#footer` does not sit below the `#contents` if the `.body` text is not longer than the `.sidebar`. The `.sidebar` is absolute positioned and the `.body` has a margin left so I don't use any floats to keep the `.body` width variable.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I can make the `#footer` sit below the `#contents` if this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually, this is easy done like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qPtXL/4/

```
parent: overflow: hidden
left: float: left
content: overflow: hidden
```

no noob's display: table-cell and etc ;)

absolute position takes elements away from flow. this is like new independent layer in photoshop. the only thing u can do is to set it's position and height\width relative to the closest parent with position: relative

IE6:
[image]
http://jsfiddle.net/qPtXL/10/

Comment: I like this method but it does not work in IE6 and has to support it! Can include seperate CSS for IE6 if you have a work around?

Comment: Lovely thanks! Do I need the `position: relative` it seems to work fine without?!

Comment: friendly speaking i don't know. sometimes helps zoom:1, sometimes position: relative. i am not pro in IE6 bugs, i just use my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try out by adding the float elements in your CSS. Here is the float fix for your issue. I have removed some properties from your CSS and added few.
The following will be your CSS.

```
#header, #footer { border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px; font-size: 20px; }
#contents { position: relative; background: url(../img/sidebar.gif) repeat-y; }
#contents .sidebar { width: 220px; padding: 20px; float:left}
#contents .body { padding: 20px 20px 20px 0; margin-left: 280px;  border: 1px solid green; }
.clearfix:after { content: "."; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; visibility: hidden;}
```

And you need to add the "clearfix" class in your HTML.

```
<div id="contents" class="clearfix">
```

Thank You,
Ramesh